# Conditionally execute a query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am in a situation where I have to write a query for a reporting system using SQL Server.  Unfortunately, the reporting system can't use SQL with `IF` statements.  So I am trying to write a query where I need to replace an `IF EXISTS` statement with `CASE` statements.

But when I do, I get this error:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 62
> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
>
> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 74
> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Regarding my query, the empty GUID below is just a placeholder for a variable that will be coming from the reporting software.

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @libID uniqueidentifier = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'

SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN @libID = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' 
            THEN (SELECT fc.libraryID, fc.librarySessionID, 
            CASE 
                WHEN ub.bookTitle IS NOT NULL THEN 'Completed'
            ELSE 'Incomplete'
            END AS completionStatus,
            DATEADD(MINUTE, 0, MIN(eventTimeStamp)) AS timeStarted
            FROM vw_fullCatalog fc INNER JOIN vw_fullReaderList rl ON fc.readerID = rl.readerID 
                LEFT JOIN vw_unavailableBooks ub ON fc.librarySessionID = ub.librarySessionID
            WHERE rl.readerID <> 'ry5'
            GROUP BY fc.libraryID, fc.readerID, fc.librarySessionID, bookTitle)
        ELSE
            (SELECT fc.libraryID, fc.librarySessionID, 
                WHEN ub.bookTitle IS NOT NULL THEN 'Completed'
            ELSE 'Incomplete'
            END AS completionStatus,
            DATEADD(MINUTE, 0, MIN(eventTimeStamp)) AS timeStarted
            FROM vw_fullCatalog fc INNER JOIN vw_fullReaderList rl ON fc.readerID = rl.readerID 
                LEFT JOIN vw_unavailableBooks ub ON fc.librarySessionID = ub.librarySessionID
            WHERE rl.readerID <> 'ry5'
            AND fc.librarySessionID = '1e4b5e3a-1896-4871-af9f-78cb31e946ef'
            GROUP BY fc.libraryID, fc.readerID, fc.librarySessionID, bookTitle)
        END
```

Does anyone know what the error is referring to?

Thanks!

Comment: `case` is an *expression*, not a control-of-flow statement - you need `if <expression> begin...end else begin...end`

Comment: This feels like something that has been covered in one of your (many) prior questions; I recall discussing fundamentals with you several times over the years. Though, finding an example specific problem in one of your questions might well be difficult; you have been asking SQL Server question for 11 years, after all.

Comment: Can you clarify *the reporting system can't use SQL with IF statements* - if you can submit a sql batch with a `declare` variable assignment followed by a `select` then what's the issue, SQL Server executes the batch and returns data to be consumed by the reporting tool... which you haven't specified; what happens if you *do* have `if... begin..end`?

Comment: @ThomA I know thank you, in this instance I can only use CASE statements and can't figure out how to get through the logic with only that.  I will delete this since others seem bothered.

Comment: I can't see why you need to be duplicating your query here at all, you just need standard boolean and/or logic in your `where` clause, perhaps `(AND fc.librarySessionID = '1e4b5e3a-1896-4871-af9f-78cb31e946ef' or @libID = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')`

Comment: @DaleK I'm sorry, I was reading a website `(https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-sql-server-case-statement/)` and they mentioned case statement, my apologies

Comment: @Stu wouldn't it need an `IF` statement though?  Because I need to check to see if the incoming value is `'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'`.  If it is, then I can't have the `AND fc.librarySessionID =` in the `WHERE` part

Comment: You need to practice your AND/OR logic what Stu has posted it logically equivalent to what you have shown.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell well why don't you test it?

Comment: @Stu the reporting software doesn't understand `IF` statements. Only `CASE` statements. Its Tableau btw.  It connects to a SQL Server and executes the SQL you typed in.  But it can't use IF/THEN type of things

Comment: Um, again, it doesn't understand `case` statements either. The fact it's an *expression* and returns a *single scalar typed value* is the root of your confusion. However as above, you do not need it for the example you have shown.

Comment: @Stu I think it would if I could figure out how to write it with skills.  When I run my query in sql server, is when I get those 2 errors.

Comment: Of course you get errors @SkyeBoniwell, that's not how you use a *case expression*. Have you missed the comments above where we explain you don't need it, you're thinking procedurally, not logically. Please test the suggestion I posted above.

Comment: In `AND (fc.librarySessionID = '1e4b5e3a-1896-4871-af9f-78cb31e946ef' OR @libID = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')` the part after the OR is TRUE when `@libID` is equal to this null guid and the part before the OR doesn't matter in this case. Therefore, this condition is equivalent to not having the condition `fc.librarySessionID = '1e4b5e3a-1896-4871-af9f-78cb31e946ef'` in this case. It means that the part after the OR does automatically switch the previous condition on or off. Therefore neither a IF nor a CASE is required!

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I don't follow.... I would that fix it?

Comment: I highly recommend reading up on AND/OR logic and truth tables, you can't write SQL without them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xquery/0596006349/ch03s11.html#:~:text=an%20and%20expression%20returns%20true,of%20its%20operands%20is%20true.

Comment: @DaleK or pretty much any programming language logic!

Comment: @Stu well yes :) but one step at a time, seems OP is just learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the `where` clause used below is logically equivalent to the branching construct you are trying to achieve:

```
SELECT fc.libraryID, fc.librarySessionID, 
  CASE WHEN ub.bookTitle IS NOT NULL THEN 'Completed'
  ELSE 'Incomplete'
  END AS completionStatus,
DATEADD(MINUTE, 0, MIN(eventTimeStamp)) AS timeStarted
FROM vw_fullCatalog fc 
JOIN vw_fullReaderList rl ON fc.readerID = rl.readerID 
LEFT JOIN vw_unavailableBooks ub ON fc.librarySessionID = ub.librarySessionID
WHERE rl.readerID <> 'ry5'
    AND (
     fc.librarySessionID = '1e4b5e3a-1896-4871-af9f-78cb31e946ef' 
     OR @libID = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
    )
GROUP BY fc.libraryID, fc.readerID, fc.librarySessionID, bookTitle;
```

Comment: I see light now in tunnel I think!  So if @libID is all zero, it returns everything as if no constraint on `librarySessionID`?

Comment: Yes, exactly! That's called Boolean logic. `FALSE OR FALSE = FALSE`, `FALSE OR TRUE = TRUE`, `TRUE OR FALSE = TRUE`, `TRUE OR TRUE = TRUE`.

Comment: In `A OR B` if B = FALSE then the result is equal to A. If B = TRUE then the value of A doesn't matter and the result is always TRUE.